# Where to download magento security patches

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Magento has removed old archive security patches from the website, Where is alternate option to download,

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11346

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 4):

You can download it here
https://github.com/akai-z/magento1-os-patches

Or [SUPEE-11346 directly](https://github.com/akai-z/magento1-os-patches/blob/master/patches/SUPEE-11346).

---

And for old Magento versions (and old docs):

https://www.magenteiro.com/blog/magento-1/magento1-download/